# Spring boot jackson java.time.Duration

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I have create a restful web service and i try to send post request the above class

```
public class A {
    Duration availTime;
}

public class MyRest {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response<?> test(@RequestBody A ta) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);`
    }
}
```

raw request body

```
{
  "availTime": {
    "seconds": 5400,
    "nano": 0,
    "units": [
      "SECONDS",
      "NANOS"
    ]
  }
}
```

expected json result

```
 {"availTime": "PT1H30M"}
```

and i got the above error : Failed to read HTTP message:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT),
expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.Duration value; nested exception is
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.Duration value
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As exception says `java.time.Duration` can be created only from `int`, `float` or `string` but you are providing a Json object.

Define your Duration class as

```
public class Duration {

    private long seconds;
    private long nano;
    private List<String> units;

    // setters / getters
}
```

Now your request will map from class `A`

**Edit 1**
In case you still want to map to `java.time.Duration`, then you need to change your request body.
**Case 1 (int)**

- Request Body

  {
    "availTime": 5400
  }
- Output

  {"availTime":"PT1H30M"}

**Case 2 (float)**

- Request Body

  {
    "availTime": 5400.00
  }
- Output

  {"availTime":"PT1H30M"}

**Case 3 (string)**

- Request Body

  {
    "availTime": "PT5400S"
  }
- Output

  {"availTime":"PT1H30M"}

For all above three cases to work add dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Class A should be modified as

```
public class A {

    private Duration availTime;

    // for json output of duration as string 
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)
    public Duration getAvailTime() {
        return availTime;
    }

    public void setAvailTime(Duration availTime) {
        this.availTime = availTime;
    }
}
```

To Print request body as json

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ta));
```

If you still want to map your existing request body, then you need to write your custom deserializer for Duration class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes but Duration class already exist it is member of java.time

Comment: Yes but it can only be created using int, float, or string. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/DurationDeserializer.java#L48

Comment: With Jackson JSR310 format, durations default to being shown as a number (of seconds). Disable the SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMP on your object mapper and the duration will appear as ISO 8601 string (PT12H format)